# Replacing 'add to cart' with a font icon

Tags: css, shopping-cart, addtocart

I would like to replace my 'add to cart' as well as my 'view details' button texts for (font) icons. Does anyone know a best practice way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<button><i>`-icon-character-`</i> Add to cart</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I do. Edit your theme (or create a new one by copying the default theme for example) and put an `<img/>` tag where the 'add to cart' text was.

---

*credits to @7ochem*
This in the correct place in the right file will do the trick. You'll have to find that on your own though.

> `<button><i>-icon-character-</i> Add to cart</button>`